# armv7 and xcode 4.5

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, armv7

I just sent my app to itunes using xcode 4.5 The app is compatible with iphone 3.5 screen and 4 screen. And with the iPad. When I go to binary details it says this:

Supported Architectures : armv7

Whats this mean? Will my app be compatible with all iPhones? Because it should work in any iphone model or ipad model. If no, how can I make it compatible with all devices (adding other architectures?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your app will run on the 3GS and later devices, assuming they meet your deployment target operating system version. To run on earlier devices, you need to build for ARM v6 as well, something I'm not sure you can do in Xcode 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

XCode 4.5.x only supports armv7 architecture :

**Changes in Xcode 4.5.x for ios 6**

1. Xcode 4.5.x (and later) does **not** support generating armv6 binaries.
2. Now includes **iPhone 5/armv7s** support.
3. The minimum supported deployment target with Xcode 4.5.x or later is **iOS 4.3**.
4. The minimum support for iPhone is **iPhone 3GS** or later as earlier versions use armv6.

Answer (score -2):

Interesting question, to avoid opening another similar question, what happen if I build my app for submission with armv6, armv7 architectures, iOS6 sdk, xCode 4.5 and deployment target 4.3?

I currently have armv6,armv7 Build settings under Architectures. [Screenshot](http://cloud.takeitsimple.com/image/033J1a423738)

With these settings I can successfully build and install my app to iPhone4,iPad3 devices and archive for Ad-hoc distribution without any warning about armv6.

Stefano

Comment: Answers are for answers only, if you have a follow-up question, create a new question - that's how SO works.